# If $T(v) \otimes w + v \otimes S(w)=0$ are the skew-symmetric operators $T$ and $S$ zero?

Tags: linear-algebra, riemannian-geometry, inner-products, tensor-products, skew-symmetric-matrices

Let $V,W$ be finite-dimensional real inner product spaces, and let
$T \in \text{Hom}(V,V), S \in  \text{Hom}(W,W)$ be **skew-symmetric operators.**

Define the following map $\phi \in \text{Hom}(V\otimes W,V\otimes W)$ by requiring
$$
\phi(v \otimes w)=T(v) \otimes w + v \otimes S(w).
$$
Now, suppose that $\phi=0$ is the zero element. Does $T=0,S=0$?

---

If we remove the requirement of skew-symmetry, then this is not true, e.g. one can take $T=id, S=-id$.

I managed to prove this when $\dim V=\dim W=2$:

In that case every skew-symmetric map can be identified with $\begin{pmatrix} 0 & a \\\ -a & 0 \end{pmatrix}$, so the computation reduces to something easy.

Comment: $0 \otimes w + v \otimes 0$ is zero; $0_V \otimes w= (0 \cdot 0_V) \otimes w=0 \cdot ( 0_V \otimes w)=0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume $\phi = T\otimes \text{id}_W + \text{id}_V\otimes S =0$.

Then, for $v,v' \in V, w \in W\backslash \{0\}$, we have $\langle w,Sw\rangle = 0$ and therefore
\begin{align}
0 &= \langle v'\otimes w, \phi(v\otimes w)\rangle \\
&= \langle v'\otimes w, v\otimes Sw+ Tv\otimes w\rangle\\
&=\langle v',v\rangle \langle w,Sw\rangle + \langle v',Tv\rangle\|w\|^2 \\
&= \langle v',Tv\rangle\|w\|^2
\end{align}

Since this is true for all $v,v'\in V$, we have $T = 0$. By the same argument, $S = 0$.

Comment: Thanks! That is a very neat solution.